# Grant a user remote admin rights for dns management Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

Im connecting to a remote dns server trough a APS.NET app. if i use the default admin account it works fine but when trying to use a other admin account named DNS i get.

```
[Exception: Unable to enum zone: Access is denied. ]
RowanvaleSW.DNSAutomation.Zones.EnumZone(String Zone, String Server, NetworkCredential DNSCredentials) +3599
```

Is there anything else i need to do then place the user in the Administrator group?

Answer (score 1):

From your DNS console, right click on server, choose Properties. On Security tab add user and give him appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The account needs to be a member of the DNSAdmins security group.  Also if they are a DNS admin then it wouldn't hurt to add them to the DNSProxyUpdate group as well if their job function requires it.

Comment: This is a remote server not in the domain and using a local user. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Under computer management->System tools->Local users and groups->groups verify that the DNSAdmins group doesn't exist.  It should be created as part of adding the DNS role.  If not then as much as I'd advise against it I guess you'll just have to add them to the local administrators group.